# Blocking specific websites from browser (PC and phone) while preventing myself from unblocking them without content of others

Tags: browser, blocking, hosts-file

I am trying to find a PC software (and app for phone) to block specific websites, and only the person with certain privilege (e.g. who knows the password) can unblock certain websites.

(I haven't yet bought any new phone. So any OS (I-OS or Android or Windows) is OK if it has what I am seeking)

I know I can edit hosts file. But I can edit that file freely.

Some recommended working without administrator privilege so that I can't work with hosts file. But there are some apps that don't work without administrator privilege.

Is there any other solution?

Alternatively, if there is any phone OS that allows me to delete the default internet browser, then that will be great, too.

Comment: In my opinion, Administrator is like God, there's nothing it cannot do. So, I think the answer to your question is: IMPOSSIBLE.

Comment: @DavidDai But fortunately I am just a naive user. So even if technically administrator can do everything, likely there are things I can't do, like hacking password that is used to block specific websites.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to block access to certain websites on a PC as well as a phone (smartphone, I assume)

I asked a [somewhat similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/789149/could-i-access-a-blocked-website-via-a-virtual-machine-if-the-host-os-has-the-we) a while ago and the short answer is you can't. Well, there isn't a foolproof solution to prevent people from accessing what they want, given that they're determined and technically adept.

That being said, if you have a wireless router that'll be used to access the Internet on your PC or phone, you could use [OpenDNS FamilyShield](http://www.opendns.com/home-internet-security/parental-controls/opendns-familyshield/) which lets you block access to certain categories of websites through [DNS blocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_blocking).

All you need to do is [configure your router](https://support.opendns.com/forums/21618374) to use FamilyShield's DNS servers:

```
FamilyShield’s IPs:

208.67.222.123
208.67.220.123
```

This is certainly not foolproof and can be bypassed as can every other Internet censorship measure, but it's fairly effective and easy to use/configure. To remove the filter, simply change the DNS server IPs to the defaults.

Additionally, you might also want to install and set up [K9 Web Protection](http://www1.k9webprotection.com/) on your PC.