# How to enforce blocking of sites if Opera is installed?

Tags: website, opera, blocking

With [Opera Turbo](http://www.opera.com/turbo) active, sites blocked in `etc/hosts` can be still visited. (Turbo takes their content from Opera servers.) It there a way to create

(1) blacklist of sites (not editable by users) which Opera users cannot visit even with Turbo

or

(2) a way to disable Turbo so users cannot re-enable it?

In other words, once Opera is installed in the PC, standard ways to block sites can be circumvented simply by using this browser. How to put the restrictions back into effect?

Comment: You might want to [check out this question](https://superuser.com/questions/789149/could-i-access-a-blocked-website-via-a-virtual-machine-if-the-host-os-has-the-we). It is somewhat related to yours.

Comment: The HOSTS file is not an effective way to block websites.  I suggest using a DNS provider like OpenDNS.  I suggest just blocking the proxy server, and disabling it by default, this way even if its enabled it can't be used.

Comment: @Ramhound - why not to transfer this comment into an answer? This will be beneficial also for the community. After you create an answer, feel free to delete the comment to keep the question tidy. (I'll delete my comment, too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opera Turbo does not do domain lookups locally, so you cannot easily use that to block access.

You could block access to the Opera Turbo servers from your hosts file.

By the by, a committed users will always work around whatever barriers you erect.